# Can I assign to a pointer to an array of chars from new[]

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

My class has a member declared as: `char (*buf)[]`. As I understand it, this is a pointer to a an array of characters with undefined dimension.  In my logic I want to dynamically allocate memory for this array as:

```
buf = new char[100];
```

But new returns a `char *` so the compiler is complaining with

```
 error: assigning to 'char (*)[]' from incompatible type 'char *'
```

Is there a way to store this pointer in a pointer to a char array?  If not, what's the use of being able to declare the pointer as I did above?

I think it would be useful if I can store the array pointer and later have the compiler warn me if I call `delete` (without the []).

Comment: Use `std::vector` or smart pointers instead. The pointer should be of type `char*`.

Comment: Change your member to `std::vector<char> buf` (or `std::string`, or `std::vector<unsigned char>` or `std::vector<std::byte>`) and watch all your pointer problems disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what your are trying to do with a cast:

```
char (*buf)[];
buf = (char (*)[])new char[100];

(*buf)[0] = 5; // Assignment

//delete buf; <- compiler warning
delete[] buf;
```

Comment: I've always been surprised by how hard it is to use things like `typedef char(ten_byte_ptr*)[10]; ten_byte_ptr buf;`

Comment: Is this actually safe / well-defined, since the type being passed to `delete[]` is not the same as the type that was `new`'d?

Comment: You are right, good point, possibly not, delete[] is meant to call destructors on an array of pointers.  However, since we are just using a char (not a class - no destructor) as the underlying type it will probably not cause a problem.  Like others suggested, I do think there are better ways to do this like using a vector or just using a plain char*.

Answer (score 1):

In standardese, `buf` is a "pointer to array of unknown bound of char". You cannot assign the result of a new-expression to it (because you cannot dynamically allocate an array of unknown bound).

You can assign dynamically allocated memory to a "pointer to array of char", if the array is two dimensional, e.g., `char (*ptr)[2] = new char [100][2]`.

There's an [open issue](https://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-active.html#118) with the standards group that's relevant to this. If the suggestion is adopted it will not allow the example in your post but it will allow `char (*ptr)[] = new char [100][2]`.